# VB: Statement appear outside of a method body

Tags: vb.net

My current syntax is giving an error statement cannot appear outside of method body reference.

```
  If tube = "1" Then (xlnk = Mono) AndAlso (xlnkh = xmwp) AndAlso (xLnkl = xmwp)
        If tube = "2" Then (xS1 = Monom) AndAlso (xS1h = xhmwp) AndAlso (RS1 = xmwp)
        If tube = 3 Then (xRS2M = Mono) AndAlso (xRS2 = xhmwp) AndAlso (RS2l = xlmwp)
End If
```

Comment: That `End If` is just kind of hanging there, isn't it?

Comment: @LarsTech: Can you give an example reference?

Comment: You should watch [Excel VBA Introduction Part 13 - If Statements](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=EsuDf8AsOXc&index=14&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).

Comment: I'm not sure what your code is doing. Are you trying to assign `xlnk = Mono`?  `AndAlso` is for continued evaluation, not for "and do this too".

Answer (score 2):

`AndAlso` doesn't do what you think it does. It's a logical AND for boolean operations (the `AND` keyword is only a bitwise AND, not logical). It helps determine the single True/False result. It is not a continuation for chaining statements inside the conditional check.

I think you want this, but it's hard to be sure:

```
If tube = "1" Then 
    xlnk = Mono
    xlnkh = xmwp
    xLnkl = xmwp
End If
If tube = "2" Then
    xS1 = Monom
    xS1h = xhmwp
    RS1 = xmwp
End If
If tube = "3" Then
    xRS2M = Mono
    xRS2 = xhmwp
    RS2l = xlmwp
End If
```

Also note I added quotes around `"3"`, to match the other comparisons. It's important to understand that `3` and `"3"` **are not the same thing!**

Finally, read the error message again:

> Statement outside of method body

I see statements in this code, but I don't see any method. What Sub/Function is this code part of?

Comment: I was able to add this in and it was clear but i'm still getting declaration and exceptions are not defined and expression is not a method.

Comment: @Diego83 I dont say this to be rude but you definitely need to learn a bit more before you jump into coding. If you are getting errors because the variables havent been declared then you need to declare them. Additionally people cannot help with a message alone. they need to see all of your relevent code

Comment: @Diego83 Notice the last sentence of the above answer. All your variables need to be declared with `Dim`

Comment: @Marie : I was able to declare them successfully, I did have this but couldn't fit this all on this form. It wouldn't allow, so I only put  a piece of it. Anyhow, thanks for the input.

Comment: @Diego83 as a general rule your functions should be small and discrete. If you are writing code that is too big to post a snippet on stackoverflow you likely need to restructure things.